# Take screenshot of the whole screen using JUnit and Espresso on Android

Tags: android, junit, android-espresso

I have setup JUnit and Espresso tests to take screenshots of an app - similar to what is described in this post: https://dev.to/serhuz/capturing-screenshots-on-android-with-espresso-and-junit-81f

However, some activities have a webview with a lot of text, causing the screen to have a lot of scrolls.

Is there a way to take a screenshot of the whole screen using Espresso?